# Should a warning be shown before changing the profile display name?

Tags: support, feature-request

The profile display name can only be changed once every 30 days. This is a good limitation and should not be removed. However, when editing your profile, the page does not warn you of that, or that you are going to change your display name.

For instance, if an undesired character slips its way inside the field and the user only realize his mistake after pressing the <kbd>Save profile</kbd> button. The unfortunate mistake is going to cruise its way through the internet for a whole month.

Shouldn't there be a safe guarding mechanism to prevent situations like this? A simple warning box or a grace period of a few minutes would suffice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always change your display name using profile on another site and then export that to all other sites. This will overwrite the incorrect name on the site in question.

Not ideal, but it does solve the problem.

Comment: It does work, thanks! This raises another concern though. It entirely bypasses the 30 days limitation. Isn't this a bug? *edit* It does change the value on the profile page, but not elsewhere on the site. Again isn't this a bug?

Comment: @MomemtumMori_ - nope. Not a bug.

Comment: I meant on the site as here, on the meta.

Comment: There seems to be a delay for some reason. Everything is now fine both on SO and on Meta. Accepted answer.

Comment: This workaround no longer seems to work. No matter which SE site I use, when I attempt to change my display name I get a message to the effect that I need to wait until the 30-day period expires.