# Accidentally changed display name, can't revert

Tags: support, status-completed, profile-page, user-interface, display-names

I edited my profile and somehow ended up adding an accidental keystroke to the beginning of my display name. Now I can't change back -- the site tells me I have to wait until March before I can change it again.

Could a helpful admin please step in and fix it?

I can see how incessant changing could be a problem, but allowing for rollback within, say, an hour would hardly hurt, I hope. Could this be changed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've changed it back for you. I've also edited at least one comment that pinged you using your changed display name so it doesn't look out of place.

That would be a good feature request: allow rolling back a display name once with the caveat that it can't be edited again in 30 days, similar to how you can undo a comment upvote without being able to cast it again.

Comment: I think there's a 15-minute grace period.

Comment: @Emrakul: Oh, yeah, there is. Was it 15 minutes or 5 minutes, I don't remember. Hmm. In this case I'd have to say the OP noticed a little too late. Perhaps a confirmation dialog when a display name change is detected would work better.

Comment: @Emrakul: [The sidebar read my mind](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255369/should-a-warning-be-shown-before-changing-the-profile-display-name?rq=1)

Comment: The sidebar read your mind? It's a Christmas miracle!

Comment: Many thanks! Should I post the rollback feature request as a separate question?

Comment: @tripleee: No need. Per the above comments, you can return to the profile edit within a 15-minute grace period. Although, you'll first have to notice the change in order to roll it back...

Comment: That was my problem.  I only noticed when somebody pinged me (the comment you changed, no doubt) at which point it was too late.  An hour and/or a warning would be a welcome safeguard if rollback can't be easily implemented.

Comment: I did the same, would you be able to change mine back?

Comment: @RyanCameron.Me: Sorry for the late reply. Looks like you've been able to change your name again since your comment. Let me know if you need any more help.