# Had an identity crisis, decided I want to revert my name change

Tags: support, recent-names

I decided to change my display name to something a little bit more direct a couple days ago, but recently changed my mind. Unfortunately, I'm unable to revert back to my old display name, as I can only change it once every 30 days.

Is there a friendly admin that could change it back so I don't have to wait until the 24th of October?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'd have to use the contact button at the bottom of any page. I don't think a regular diamond mod can do that

Comment: look in the footer of every page.  Look for "contact us".  Click it and send a message.  Far better than a meta post for administrative type questions

Comment: Though, it would have to be a really bad naming decision for me to want to bother the SO staff for something like this. Just my opinion. Something like "IAmSuchAnAss" but not something like "ColingTheLinuxGuy"

Comment: @codeMagic - It looks like mods can do it. Not saying that they will, but see [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285381/accidentally-changed-display-name-cant-revert) where BoltClock did it.

Comment: @theB Ah, good to know. Thanks! Still either flagging one of your posts (not yours but the person asking), using the contact button, or asking a mod in a chat might be better suited here than a meta post

Comment: @theB that is exactly why I posted this. never thought I'd get this much hate for asking.

if it weren't for Normal Human's answer, I probably would've deleted this question after coming back and seeing all the downvotes

Comment: I didn't downvote you. I was adding context Voting on meta is weird.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a workaround: join a new SE community and change your name there, choosing the option to propagate the change to all communities.

Comment: Cool trick.​​​​

Comment: Someone said this workaround [no longer works](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255369/should-a-warning-be-shown-before-changing-the-profile-display-name?rq=1#comment114573_255370).

Comment: @approxiblue I have certainly used it after that comment was made.